# Jquery Sortable .toArray script error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Could someone PLEASE, for the love of god, tell me why this works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clause_sort').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var clauseOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        alert(clauseOrder);     
        }
        });         
}); // End of ready
```

And this, inexplicably doesn't:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#clause_sort').sortable();

$("#generate").click(function(){
var clauseOrder = $("'#clause_sort").sortable('toArray').toString();
alert(clauseOrder);
});

}); // End of ready
```

I've not included the HTML, but #clause_sort is a nested set of Divs (that do indeed become sortable) and #generate is a button. In the first example everything works, and when the order is changed it instantly generates an alert with a string containing the clause order.

I only need the order, however, when the user clicks a button. According to everything I can find on the topic, the second code should work. Instead clicking the button generates an a script error.

I have considered simply sticking with the first method, and having a global variable that just keeps getting updated. The problem with this is: 1) the user may not change the order of the list at all (so the variable remains unset); and 2) its driving me insane why it won't work, so I want an answer anyway!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace for:

```
var clauseOrder = $("#clause_sort").sortable('toArray').toString(); 
// remove redundant quote
```

Comment: Oh my GOD, thank you. Unbelievable I've been staring at it for hours and missed that one idiotic typo.

Probably the stupidest question I've ever asked but great to have it sorted.

Thanks again.